# How do I access HTTP request headers in HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI?

Tags: perl, http, cgi

I'm using [`HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI) for a light-weight HTTP server. That gives me a CGI object in a callback function when a HTTP request is accepted.

How can I access the incoming HTTP headers, especially non-standard headers?
The environment variables are only the standard ones.

`cgi->param` gives me only the form parameters.

Thanks!
chris

Comment: chris, I substituted *attributes* for *headers* in your question. If that's not what you meant, roll back my change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says in [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3A%3AServer%3A%3ASimple):

> You can, if you really want, define parse_headers() and parse them raw yourself.

Comment: thanks!  you put me on the right way!
function headers will give me the arguments without parsing for myself.

regards, 
chris

Answer (score 0):

Define the `headers` method to receive the headers.

```
sub headers
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $headers = shift;
    my @h = @{$headers};

    while (0 + @h)
    {
        my $k = shift @h;
        my $v = shift @h;

        print STDERR "header >> $k: $v\n";
    }
}
```