# Using HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI, how do I get the headers?

Tags: perl

Basically, my question is similar to 
[How do I access HTTP request headers in HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093160/how-do-i-access-http-request-headers-in-httpserversimplecgi)

The answer was to use  parse_headers(), but there was no example how to use it properly.  I tried to use  parse_headers()  but I'm not getting any result, it just stops at  parse_headers() like the program is stucked.  I couldn't add a comment on the question above since I don't have enough rep to do so, so I created this new question.

Below is my sample code, basically the example code from CPAN just added the parse_headers:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
{
package MyWebServer;

use HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI;
our @ISA = qw(HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI);
use Data::Dumper;

my %dispatch = (
    '/hello.cgi' => \&resp_hello,
    # ...
);

sub handle_request {
    my $self = shift;
    my $cgi  = shift;

    my $path = $cgi->path_info();
    my $handler = $dispatch{$path};

    my $header = $self->parse_headers();
    open F,qq{>>~/MyWebServer.log};
    my $dump = Data::Dumper->Dump([$header], [qw($header)]);
    print F $dump;
    close F;

    if (ref($handler) eq "CODE") {
        print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
        $handler->($cgi);

    } else {
        print "HTTP/1.0 404 Not found\r\n";
        print $cgi->header,
              $cgi->start_html('Not found'),
              $cgi->h1('Not found'),
              $cgi->end_html;
    }
}

sub resp_hello {
    my $cgi  = shift;   # CGI.pm object
    return if !ref $cgi;

    my $who = $cgi->param('name');

    print $cgi->header,
          $cgi->start_html("Hello"),
          $cgi->h1("Hello $who!"),
          $cgi->end_html;
}

} # end of package MyWebServer

# start the server on port 8080
my $pid = MyWebServer->new(8080)->background();
print "Use 'kill $pid' to stop server.\n";
```

Only added this part:

```
    my $header = $self->parse_headers();
    open F,qq{>>~/MyWebServer.log};
    my $dump = Data::Dumper->Dump([$header], [qw($header)]);
    print F $dump;
    close F;
```

My objective is to get all the headers and dump it into a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
sub headers {
    my( $self, $headers ) = @_;
    if( $headers ){
        $self->{__last_headers} = { @$headers };
    }
    return $self->{__last_headers};
}
```

Then inside `handle_request` use `my $header = $self->headers();`

FWIW, i'm curious why you're using HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI instead of Mojolicious or Dancer or even HTTP::Server::Simple::PSGI.  https://metacpan.org/pod/PSGI is portability.

Comment: It worked!  Thanks a lot!  Also, I'll try those you have suggested, first time seeing them.